# javascript disable table row and its content

Tags: javascript

I am try to disable some particular rows in a html table,by using 
rowObject.disabled=true; but it does not seems to be work?in each row some 5 columns are available(it contains radio and textboxes)...how can i do this?
                      many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "disabled"?  What do you expect to happen to these disabled rows, and how does this differ from what they do when "enabled"?

Comment: It is not javascript, are you using some jQuery plugin or similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you want some form elements to be disabled, you must set the disabled property for each of them, placing it on their parent is not enough.